# Redirecting users when they have made 10+ submissions in one hour

Tags: php, mysql

The code below is supposed to check to see if a user has made an addition to a MySQL database table called "submission" more than 10 times in the last day.  If the answer is yes, then the user is re-redirected back to the index page.  As far as I can tell, it works just fine.

How could I modify to make it do the re-direct if the user has submitted 10 or more items in the last hour?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$queryuidcount = "select loginid from submission where TO_DAYS(datesubmitted) = TO_DAYS(NOW()) AND loginid = '$uid'"; 
$uidresult = mysql_query($queryuidcount);

if (mysql_num_rows($uidresult) >= 11)
{

   session_write_close();
   header("Location:http://www.domain.com/sample/index.php");
   exit;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$queryuidcount = "select COUNT(*) from submission where datesubmitted > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 hours) AND loginid = '$uid'"; 
$uidresult = mysql_query($queryuidcount);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $uidresult )) {
   if ($row['COUNT(*)'] >= 10) {
       session_write_close();
       header("Location:http://www.domain.com/sample/index.php");
       exit;
   }
}
```

This code gives you a count which you can use to redirect.

Comment: +1 -- but replace that string concat with a parameterized query please.

Answer (score 1):

If `datesubmitted` is timestamp you can try something like this. -Sorry I don't have php or mysql currently installed so I hope this works.

```
$queryuidcount = "select COUNT(*) from submission where datesubmitted > DATE_SUB(NOW(),HOURS,1) AND loginid = '$uid'";
```